# SQLException: ResultSet closed

Tags: java, hikaricp

I'm trying to execute method which should create a new object with fields from database, and everytime i run this code im getting SQLException: ResultSet closed.

```
 public DatabasedClient getDatabaseClient(int clientDatabaseid){
    if(DatabaseClientUtil.isInDatabase(clientDatabaseid)){
        return DatabaseClientUtil.getDBClient(clientDatabaseid);
    }else{
        try{
            System.out.println("Trying to find user in db");
            ResultSet rs = fbot.getStorage().query("select * from database_name where clientDBId = " + clientDatabaseid);
            System.out.println("deb " + rs.getString("nick"));
            while (rs.next()) {
                DatabasedClient databasedClient = new DatabasedClient(clientDatabaseid);
                databasedClient.setUid(rs.getString("uid"));
                databasedClient.setNick(rs.getString("nick"));
                databasedClient.setLastConnect(rs.getLong("lastConnected"));
                databasedClient.setLastDisconnect(rs.getLong("lastDisconnect"));
                databasedClient.setTimeSpent(rs.getLong("timeSpent"));
                databasedClient.setLongestConnection(rs.getLong("longestConnection"));
                return databasedClient;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Im using hikari, here are methods from AbstractStorage class

```
@Override
public void execute(String query) throws SQLException {
    try (Connection connection = getConnection()){
        connection.prepareStatement(query).executeUpdate();
    }
}

@Override
public ResultSet query(String query) throws SQLException {
    try (Connection connection = getConnection()) {
        return  connection.prepareStatement(query).executeQuery();
    }
}
```

Screenshot from error
[image]

I hope someone will help me with this.

Comment: You have a `return` statement inside the `while` loop...

Comment: what is the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the exact error you are seeing is being caused by the following line of code:

```
System.out.println("deb " + rs.getString("nick"));
```

You are trying to access the result set before you advance the cursor to the first record.  Also, your method `getDatabaseClient`  is returning a single object which conceptually maps to a single expected record from the query.  Hence, iterating once over the result set would seem to make sense.  Taking all this into consideration, we can try the following:

```
try {
    System.out.println("Trying to find user in db");
    ResultSet rs = fbot.getStorage().query("select * from database_name where clientDBId = " + clientDatabaseid);
    // do not access the result set here

    if (rs.next()) {
        DatabasedClient databasedClient = new DatabasedClient(clientDatabaseid);
        databasedClient.setUid(rs.getString("uid"));
        databasedClient.setNick(rs.getString("nick"));
        databasedClient.setLastConnect(rs.getLong("lastConnected"));             
        databasedClient.setLastDisconnect(rs.getLong("lastDisconnect"));
        databasedClient.setTimeSpent(rs.getLong("timeSpent"));
        databasedClient.setLongestConnection(rs.getLong("longestConnection"));
        return databasedClient;
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Now its okay, no errors but..
I'm trying to get a clientDBId 4028 from a database and the method still returns me all the time null, even if the user exists in database

Comment: I don't know your particular API, so I won't be of much more help here.